# what is the difference between this rust function about lifetime

Tags: rust, lifetime

Rust lifetime concept is so confused for me. I have two functions below:

```
fn test1<'a, 'b: 'a>(x: &'a u32, y: &'b u32) -> &'a u32 {
    if x > y {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}

fn test2<'a, 'b: 'a>(x: &'b u32, y: &'a u32) -> &'a u32 {
    if x > y {
        x
    } else {
        y
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = 5;

    {
        let b = 6;
        let c = test1(&a, &b);
        println!("{}", c);
    }

    {
        let b = 6;
        let c = test2(&a, &b);
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

This program can be compiled and result is

```
6
6
```

However, I cannot figure out the difference between **test1** and **test2**
Can anybody explain it?

Comment: Since you defined b lifetime as `'b: 'a` those functions are exactly the same. You might as well just skip the `'b` lifetime and use `'a` only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rust lifetime limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75626387/rust-lifetime-limitation)

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR:** There is no practical difference.

What you have to understand is that Rust lifetime indications are not strict equality assertion, instead they denote a "longer than" relationship. So when you write:

```
fn foo<'a> (x: &'a i32)
```

You are telling the compiler that: "in order to call `foo`, there must exist some lifetime `'a` and `x` must live at least as long as `'a` (but `x` may live longer than that)".

Going back to your function definitions:

```
fn test1<'a, 'b: 'a>(x: &'a u32, y: &'b u32) -> &'a u32
```

This means:

- There must exist some lifetime `'a` such that `x` lives *at least as long as* `'a` (but may live longer).
- There must exist some lifetime `'b` that is *at least as long as* `'a` (but may be the same) such that `y` lives *at least as long as* `'b` (but may live longer).
- And the return value cannot live longer than `'a`.

Since there are no other constraints on `'b`, the compiler is always free to pick `'b = 'a` and the code will compile as long as the constraints on `'a` are satisfied.

When you call the function, the compiler searches for some lifetimes `'a` and `'b` that match the constraints above:

```
let a = 5;
{
    let b = 6;
    let c = test1(&a, &b);
    println!("{}", c);
}
```

- The return value cannot live longer than `'a` so `'a` must start at the function call (because the return value does not exist before) and end at the closing brace at the earliest.
- Here `x` is `a` and `x` must live at least as long as `'a`. Since `a` is defined before the function call and is still alive at the closing brace, everything is fine.
- Here `y` is `b` and `y` must live at least as long as `'b`. If we choose `'b = 'a` then everything is fine since `b` is defined before the function call and lives until the closing brace.

Therefore, the compiler chooses `'a == 'b` starting at the function call and ending at the closing brace. Both variables `a` and `b` live longer than that but this is fine since lifetime annotations for parameters are lower bounds on the true lifetimes of the corresponding variables.

Note: the same reasoning applies to your second function and again the compiler can always pick `'b = 'a` whenever all the other constraints are met.

Comment: In my code, lifetime of a starts from "let a =5" and ends at "the last }", lifetime of b starts from "let b = 6;" and ends at "the last but one }". So how can understand "  'b: 'a " ?

Comment: `'a` is _not_ the lifetime of `a`. So yes, the lifetime of `a` starts at the `let a =…` line and ends at the final closing brace, but `'a` is much shorter than that.