# How does Rust combine its multiple lifetime?

Tags: rust

The code is as follows:

```
fn inner<'a:'b, 'b>(x:&'a i32, _y:&'b i32) -> &'b i32 {
    x
}

fn main() {
  let a = 1;
  {
      let b = 2;
      inner(&b, &a);
      inner(&a, &b);
  }
}
```

The bound `'a:'b` in function `inner` means that the lifetime `'a` lasts longer than `'b`. In the above example, the lifetime of variable `b` is shorter then `a`.  The borrow checker should fail when encountering `inner(&b, &a)`. However, the code can compile. Can someone provide some explanations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the difference between this rust function about lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60964731/what-is-the-difference-between-this-rust-function-about-lifetime)

Comment: @Jmb To me that question looks quite different.

Comment: @SvenMarnach but the answer to that question also applies to this one. TLDR: if a function parameter has lifetime `'a`, this means that the passed reference must live _at least_ as long as `'a`, not _exactly_ as long as `'a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lifetime annotations describe the lifetimes of the borrows, not of the borrowed variables. In both calls to `inner()`, all borrows last until the end of the call, so the compiler can infer identical lifetimes for them, so the bound `'a: 'b` is fulfilled in both cases.