# Rust lifetime limitation

Tags: rust

```
fn f<'a: 'b, 'b>(x: &'a i32, mut y: &'b i32) -> &'b i32 {
    y = x;  
      
    y
}

let long_var = 1;
let long_lifetime = &long_var;
{
    let short_var = 2;
    let short_lifetime = &short_var; 
    // it works, why?
    let x = f(short_lifetime, long_lifetime); 
};
```

There is limitation `'a: 'b` in the function `f`, so why `let x = f(short_lifetime, long_lifetime);`  works?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637911/how-can-this-instance-seemingly-outlive-its-own-parameter-lifetime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because lifetimes in function parameters are *bounds,* not strict lifetimes. So when you call `f(short_lifetime, long_lifetime)`, the compiler tries to find lifetimes `'a` and `'b` such that:

- `short_lifetime` lives *at least* as long as `'a` (*but it may live longer*),
- `long_lifetime` lives *at least* as long as `'b` (*but it may live longer*),
- `'a` is at least as long as `'b` (but they may be equal),
- the returned value lives *at most* as long as `'b` (but it may live shorter).

One possible solution is to take `'a == 'b` lasting from the function call to the first closing `}`. This fits all the above constraints (`long_lifetime` actually lives longer than `'b` but that's allowed since the lifetimes are only bounds and not strict).

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60965760/5397009

Answer (score 1):

`'a: 'b` reads `'a` *outlives* `'b`. So the lifetimes in your example are reversed, `'a` is the long lifetime and `'b` is the short one. The code compiles, because you can always cast a reference from a longer lifetime to a shorter lifetime (i.e. cast a reference `&'a` to `&'b` in your case). Read more in the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#lifetime-bounds)